# Super robust SD card cleaner

Tags: partitioning, sd-card

My friend asked me to help with her SD card. I looked at it and it was completely messed up (corupted partition table, ...). She doesn't care about the data. I tried recreating partition table, but with no success (I tried everything from gparted, fdisk, console parted to windows cmd, miniTool Partition wizard). Everything failed. Basically, it said that is was completed (even linux fdisk), but when I reloaded it, everything stayed the same. So, is there any ultra-robust application that would just completely clean up whole SD card bit by bit and recreated partition table?(to have clean slaid to work with)

Comment: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/<raw_device> bs=1M`

Answer (score 1):

What you did should have solved the issue already. I think the SD card may be broken. Or it could be the card reader. Try another card or put that card into another reader and check if it works.

Answer (score 1):

The SD Association recommends the use of their [formatter.](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/)